# NcFTP batch uploading

Tags: debian, bash, ftp, readynas

I'm on a Debian box, which I can't modify in any way.

I need to upload an entire directory (and subdirs) content to my server.

The only tool I've got is ncFTP (http://www.ncftp.com/).

Can you help me write a bash script who:

- connect to xxx.myhost.com with given credentials
- put recursively the content of /mydir/*
- overwrite existing files without asking anything

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this should do the trick:

```
ncftpput -R -u username-here -p "password-here" 12.12.12.12 /remote/dir /my/local/dir
```

Of course you replace username, password, IP and directories with your information :)

Comment: Thank you! I believe this is what I've been looking for but... it hangs a few seconds then says 'Killed'. Consider that doing the same manually with ncftp works correctly. Where does it log?

Comment: Sorry! My destination folder had "/" at bottom. Now it works! Thanks :)